# Integers that are equal to the sum of their digits each raised to that digit's power

Tags: number-theory

The number 3,435 has the interesting property where

$$3435 = 3^3 + 4^4 + 3^3 + 5^5$$

That is, it equals the sum of its digits each raised to that digit's power.

What is the next larger number with the same property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like these are called Muenchhausen numbers and have a page devoted to them. See 'http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuenchhausenNumber.html'.

Comment: To avoid link rot, the only greater one is $438579088$

Comment: Also known as "perfect digit-to-digit invariant", also known as "Canouchi number" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_digit-to-digit_invariant).